# Как в Unity 3D сделать при нажатии на кнопку Canvas невидимым

Tags: unity3d

Как в Unity 3D сделать при нажатии на кнопку  Canvas невидимым

Answer (score 0):

Сам Canvas отключить нельзя, но можно отключить каждый его дочерний элемент.

```
public class CanvasFalse : MonoBehaviour {

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        foreach (Transform child in GetComponentInParent<Transform>())
        {
            GameObject cld = child.gameObject;
            cld.SetActive(false);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: '
public class CanvasFalse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CanvasGroup cv;

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        cv.alpha = 0f;

    }
}
'